# Gradle does not detect dependencies from POM deployed to Artifactory

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory

I have 3 libraries deployed to Artifactory with their POM including dependencies. However for one of the libraries Gradle is not able to detect its dependencies despite the POM being correct and uploaded.

I can't see any differences between its POM and the other 2 libraries' POMs.

Artifact A full POM (dependencies detected)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>ArtifactA</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.37478-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <description>Release - 3.8.37478.0-task/37478-3.0.19_CC_322_ga58965c8-a58965c8-20200115T1705701</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-android-extensions-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.50</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.50</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.50</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-android</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0-RC</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp-urlconnection</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
      <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxandroid</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.23.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-http-client-android</artifactId>
      <version>1.23.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
      <version>1.23.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.octo.android.robospice</groupId>
      <artifactId>robospice</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.14</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.octo.android.robospice</groupId>
      <artifactId>robospice-cache</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.14</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.octo.android.robospice</groupId>
      <artifactId>robospice-okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.14</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>okhttp-urlconnection</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.octo.android.robospice</groupId>
      <artifactId>robospice-google-http-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.14</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.arrow-kt</groupId>
      <artifactId>arrow-core-data</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.arrow-kt</groupId>
      <artifactId>arrow-effects-data</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.koin</groupId>
      <artifactId>koin-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.koin</groupId>
      <artifactId>koin-android</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
      <artifactId>converter-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.auth0.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>jwtdecode</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Artifact B full POM (dependencies not detected)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>ArtifactB</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.37478-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <description>Release - 1.1.37478.0-task/37478-V1.0.23_8_gd77bd0e-d77bd0e-20200116T0933271</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxandroid</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0-RC</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-android</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0-RC</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.arrow-kt</groupId>
      <artifactId>arrow-core-data</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.arrow-kt</groupId>
      <artifactId>arrow-effects-data</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.koin</groupId>
      <artifactId>koin-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.koin</groupId>
      <artifactId>koin-android</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.connectsdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>connect-sdk-android</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
          <artifactId/>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId/>
          <artifactId>play-services-cast</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxkotlin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
      <version>27.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>mediarouter-v7</artifactId>
      <version>27.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-cast-framework</artifactId>
      <version>16.2.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
          <artifactId/>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run `grade :Project:dependencies` it shows the dependencies for Artifact A but not those for Artifact B, and of course it shows compilation errors for those Artifact B dependencies. The Artifact B dependency itself is correctly detected, it's only its dependencies that are not.

URLs for Artifact A:

```
http://artifactory.host.net/artifactory/misc/com/example/company/ArtifactA/3.8.37478-SNAPSHOT/ArtifactA-3.8.37478-SNAPSHOT-release.aar
http://artifactory.host.net/artifactory/misc/com/example/company/ArtifactA/3.8.37478-SNAPSHOT/ArtifactA-3.8.37478-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

URLs for Artifact B:

```
http://artifactory.host.net/artifactory/misc/com/example/company/ArtifactB/1.1.37478-SNAPSHOT/ArtifactB-1.1.37478-SNAPSHOT-release.aar
http://artifactory.host.net/artifactory/misc/com/example/company/ArtifactB/1.1.37478-SNAPSHOT/ArtifactB-1.1.37478-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

I have refreshed the dependencies as well as manually deleted it from Gradle cache several times as well.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: What error or warning do you get?

Comment: @JFMeier Sorry, I don't understand the question. I get a compilation error because the dependencies of Artifact B are not included in the compilation process, specifically rxkotlin.

Comment: I mean that it would probably be helpful to add the exact error message to the question. If it is not about a POM, but a compilation error, I am not sure whether this a problem about reading a POM, but maybe a problem that dependencies are replaced/overridden/excluded somewhere.

Comment: @JFMeier There's no error message except the compilation one. However when I run `gradle dependencies` I see that Gradle reports no dependencies for Artifact B but it does correctly list the dependencies for Artifact A. Both artifacts are only declared as a dependency once in a single place. What I don't understand is how/why one is correctly detected while the other is not.

Comment: How do you consume the dependencies?

Comment: @tynn I just add the library dependency in the corresponding Gradle file, for example `implementation 'com.example.company:ArtifactA:3.8.37478-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: if you try to have an empty project that defines a dependency on Artifact B only, what will the output be (output of either compiling some source code or just running the `gradle dependencies` task)?